# HTTP Post redirect to returned url

Tags: php, curl, post, http-post, php-curl

I'm wondering if anyone can help me because I'm going crazy with this. I'm working with a company where I need to submit a form post data to a server which returns a url. I'd like to redirect the user to said link.

Below is the PHP that returns the url

```
<?php
$interface = "";
$postFields = Array(
    "action" => "credit_application_link",
    "Identification[api_key]" => "",
    "Identification[InstallationID]" => "",
    "Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]" => "",
    "Goods[Description]" => "",
    "Goods[Price]" => "",
    "Finance[Code]" => "",
    "Finance[Deposit]" => ""
);

function httpPost($interface, $postFields)
{
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $interface);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curlSession);
    return $curl_response;
}
echo $response = httpPost($interface, $postFields);
```

After some research it seems a Header Location might be the way to do it but since the url will be unique each time I'm a bit stuck.

Hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you can dynamically insert any URL with: `header('location: ' . $yourUrl);` and redirect the user.

Comment: Don't know if I'm totally getting this. But asides that, what's about using the recieved (unique) link and then change the location with javascript: window.location.replace("your.link");

Comment: Just to clear things up, I have no idea what the url will be until the server responds. So I don't know if there is a way to get the url then redirect to it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have 2 files

- post.php (you will initilize curl from here)
- response.php (you will hit this url from your curl and it will return response with dynamic url)

at post.php

```
$response = httpPost($interface, $postFields);
$response = json_decode($response,true);
header('Location: '.$response['url']);
```

at response.php

```
$data['url'] = "tranxactive.com";
return json_encode($data);
```

where

```
$interface = "response.php";
```

hope this detailed answer may help

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions. So my response should look like this? 

`$response = httpPost($interface, $postFields);
header('location: ' . $response);`

I'm not exactly sure how I would return the url in the curl response either.

Comment: let me explain in one of the best approach
your curl will hit the url path in $interface 
there you 'll have some php code to handle that request.
assume you returned tranxactive.com in response from there in this way
$data['url'] = "http://tranxactive.com";
return json_encode($data);

now at the code from where you initialize curl
$response = json_decode(httpPost($interface, $postFields),true);
header('Location: '.$response['url']);
I can update my answer for proper understanding

Comment: If you could update your answer so I fully understand that would be great!

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm not sure if I am getting confused. From your comment "assume you returned tranxactive.com in response" I want to forward the user to the returned url automatically. The returned url is displayed in the page and not the address bar. The url uses this structure is it's any help

[https://example.com/credit-application/form/m-4f8bda9b7db9f3d647778eddad27bbf5
]

Comment: what is your returned url, can you please give me url or something so that I can explain your scenario?

Comment: the url comes back as so `https://test.dekopay.com/credit-application/form/m-4f8bda9b7db9f3d647778eddad27bbf5`

but after "form/" the rest is generated automatically without any input from me as it's a third party company

Comment: and what is the url to which you hit your curl request?

Comment: can i hit this url from my curl?

Comment: I doubt it, as the company had to whitelist my ip address.

Comment: sorry, no luck from here